# How to make a base layout (header, footer, sidebar) using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, layout, header, footer, paging

I am just wondering if any of you know or has a link that could let me know the step by step of making a layout of pages or simply as just letting me create header, footer and sidebar that I could call every time I create new page using codeigniter. So that I will not encode it with every pages I make. Thank you guys :) I always appreciate your answers :)

Comment: study [this](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-controller) you can get idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. put the design that you want for header in one .php page
2. put this code in your view page where you want to show the header

`$this->load->view('header');`

do the same for footer, slidebar and all other pages that you want to include in different pages